# R shiny download xlsx with async

Tags: r, asynchronous, shiny

I want to let multiple users to download excel file. 
[This is](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/124-async-download/app.R) what I refers to; which download csv with async.

I use **openxlsx** package but failed and the minimal example is as below, thanks in advance:

```
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)
library(openxlsx)
plan(multiprocess)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Async downloadHandler test"),
  hr(),
  downloadButton("download", "Download ")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$download <- downloadHandler("example.xlsx", function(file) {

        future
        ({
          wb <- createWorkbook()
          addWorksheet(wb, "Cars")
          addWorksheet(wb, "Formula")
          x <- mtcars[1:6,]
          writeData(wb, "Cars", x, startCol = 2, startRow = 3, rowNames = TRUE)
        }) %...>%
        {             
          saveWorkbook(wb, file = "addFilterExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
        }

  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In your "saveWorkbook" command, change the "file ="addFilterExample.xlsx" to "file = file" to get the file to download.  It will create the download file named in your "downloadHandler" command.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the working example here:

```
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)
library(openxlsx)
plan(multiprocess)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Async downloadHandler test"),
  hr(),
  downloadButton("download", "Download ")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
      paste(Sys.Date(),".xlsx", sep="_")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      future({
        Sys.sleep(15)
      }) %...>%  
      { wb <- createWorkbook()
        addWorksheet(wb, "Cars")
        addWorksheet(wb, "Formula")
        x <- mtcars[1:6,]
        writeData(wb, "Cars", x, startCol = 2, startRow = 3, rowNames = TRUE) 
        saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)}
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This example runs the future in a different process, but still blocks all interaction in the app.  So I don't think this is the solution.